# Detecting a single instance of a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a unity project.In that I have a prefab where there will be multiple instances of that prefab will be generated in the scene.I want to select one instance of that prefab and change the color of that of that prefab.

```
void Update(){
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
           wallPrehab.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
}
}
```

but this changes all the instances of the prefab.How can I change it to a single object.

Comment: once you have a instance it is no-longer a prefab.

Comment: Does 'wallprehab' refers to the prefab or the instance?

Comment: @MiladQasemi Its the Prefab

Comment: Are you trying to select a object by mouse clicking on it and then change the color of that instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the color of the object by locating the instance of the prefab, not the prefab itself. Use a Raycast to locate the gameobject. (Since you are responding to mouse click event i assume that you are selecting the object which you want to change the color)

```
private RaycastHit hit;

void Update(){

    Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition), out hit);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && hit.collider){
           hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
        }

}
```

Dont forgrt to add a Collider to the prefab.

Answer (score 0):

Because all your objects use the same material it won't be possible to change ones color without affecting others , one way is to create a copy of that material and change that ones color , this way they aren't using the same material
 the only thing that you need to do differrent in your code is to get the reference to the instance not the prefab this way if you change the material at runtime a new material will be created

```
Gameobject go = Instantiate(myPrefab);
go.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
```